# When to use setX and setY

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i am using setX and setY in order to move a view on the screen. However, i read that the android first needs to calculate the views positions, otherwise it gives NullPointerException (what happand to me).
I need to know **when** to use it in order to avoid the exception. 
Until now i used it in the onCreate().
Thanks and have a good day

Answer (score 1):

You definitely **cannot** use it before or during onResume(). You would need to set a global layout listener and whenever the view has been laid out, you would move the view. However, this is not a great idea, if you want the view to be set in a certain position when the user first sees the app, it is better just to do it through xml.

If you want the view to move around while the app is running, look into the Android animation classes.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
View myView;
     @Override    
     onGlobalLayout() {
          myView.setx(100);
          myView.sety(100);

     }

     @Override
     onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
          super.onCreate(bundle);
          setContentView(layout);

          myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
          myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
     }
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried to put the code in onResume() but it seems not to work.. i want the views to be in their new positions when the user first sees the screen, do u have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any issue with applying the transformation in your layout xml:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:translationX="10dp"
    android:translationY="10dp" />
```

---

Post update, which should run on the next UI frame:

```
myView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myView.setX(50);
        myView.setY(50);
    }
});
```

Comment: This link - should help you with drag/drop issues. SetX and SetY are not always available when dragging.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html   In the more general case, trying to set x and y in onCreate() does not always work - the layout has not been set and measurements have not all been done.  You might want to look into view.post( new Runnable()...)  to get or set values after all the layout has occurred.

Comment: hi Martin can you please explain how to use view.post? i want the vies to be in their new positions when the user first sees the screen, what might work in that case? thanks

Comment: @nitz123 Since Martin is not responding, I have added a snippet of what he is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dialog at the end of onCreate method where you can ask the user if they want to continue. This will execute the code below and allows you to set your view (here: button) anywhere you desire. Try to check how to use dialog if this solution can be applied to your app. It worked for me.

```
myDialog=new Dialog(this);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
button_on_dialog=myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_on_dialog);
button_on_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        button.setX(100f);
        myDialog.dismiss();
    }
});

myDialog.show();
```